# "cp: cannot create regular file" inside snap

Tags: filesystem, snap, adb

I have been trying to use scrcpy wirelessly but facing issue **adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39); killing...**
So I decide to copy adb used by Android Sdk to scrcpy but face this issue

```
:~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools$ sudo cp adb /snap/scrcpy/233/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/
[sudo] password for harshalkantilaldhone: 
cp: cannot create regular file '/snap/scrcpy/233/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb': Read-only file system
```

Is there any way change read only property and so that I can copy adb file

Comment: The only way to change the structure of a snap package is to re-package it as far as I know. It's not possible to copy that file there. Try another directory .It's a security measure that prevents this.